# как найти ключ по значению без цикла for на python

Tags: python

представим у нас есть определенное значение и словарь, возможно ли найти ключ с таким значением без перебора?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: нет. В любом случае будет поиск по всем ключам, или до первого найденного ключа с таким значением.

Comment: Если это частая задача, то можно построить обратный словарь. Но для начала подумать о выборе другой структуры данных.

Comment: На обычном словаре без обратного словаря нельзя. Есть готовый пакет [bidict](https://github.com/jab/bidict), но это по сути и есть два словаря (прямой и обратный), обернутых в один объект

Answer (score -1):

Возможно. Можно превратить ключи и значения в списки и с помощью списков делать операции по поиску. Я сделал функцию, которая принимает список и значение, а на выходе выдаёт ключи (даёт даже несколько).

```
My_Dict = {"NotError": False, "Error1": True, "Error2": True}
def Finder(Dict, Value):
    All, Result = [list(Dict.keys()), list(Dict.values())], list()
    while Value in All[1]:
        Result.append(All[0].pop(All[1].index(Value)))
        All[1].remove(Value)
    return Result
print(Finder(My_Dict, True))
```

На выходе имеем:

> ['Error1', 'Error2']

Comment: Здесь море циклов - и решение намного хуже, чем простой перебор, и чем предложенный в комментариях обратный словарь